# Probability - binary array through a comm. channel

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

An information through a communication channel is transmitted as a binary array - an array of bits (1s and 0s). But the bits can get corrupted, 1 can turn into a 0 and 0 can turn into a 1 with a probability of $1-a$ .

The bits are transmitted independent of one another.

Seeing a lot of signals that need to be transmitted, it was acknowledged that the ratio between 0s and 1s is $3:4$ .

Find the distribution of the input array, if the output is $101$ .

Comment: I can't even start, I have no idea how to approach the problem

Comment: Start with one bit; use Bayes' Theorem: if $A_i$ is the event that the input is $i$, and $B_j$ the event that the output is $j$, for $i, j\in\{0,1\}$, then $$Pr(A_i\mid B_j)=Pr(B_j\mid A_i) Pr(A_i)/Pr(B_j),$$ where $$Pr(B_j)= Pr(B_j\mid A_0)Pr(A_0)+Pr(B_j\mid A_1)Pr(A_1).$$ These are all things you can compute from the givens. You can then use independence to write down, say, the probability that the input was 000 given an output of 101. Now repeat, replacing 000 by all possible inputs.

Comment: What about the ratio? Where would I use that information?

Comment: The ratio means $Pr(A_0)=3/4$ and $Pr(A_1)=1/4$.

Comment: All of this now suddenly makes sense :D Thanks a lot!